# Check from which directory the program was executed

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I check from which directory the program in one of the directories in PATH was executed?

For example, I am running the following command:

```
laravel
```

and would like to check where this program is actually located.

I am using [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) and get the impression that PATH variables get somehow mixed up between Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, this is what I was looking for. Just didn't know how to phrase the question properly.